# .DEM files unsupported with OSGEO?

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo

I've downloaded the .DEM files from the NASA SRTM30 dataset (found [here](https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM30/e100n90/)) however trying to open these yields `ERROR 4: "E140N90.DEM" is not recognized as a supported file format.`

This is the the same while either using the windows binaries with python bindings and OSGeo4W shell. OSGeo is using GDAL 2.2.2 and USGSDEM files are listed under the supported formats in `gdalinfo --formats`

```
 ...
 USGSDEM -raster- (rwv): USGS Optional ASCII DEM (and CDED)
 ...
```

I've also tried opening the files in QGis, which has yielded the same result. So is there another way to open the files, or convert the files into a supported file format?

Comment: Please rename the extension from `.DEM` to `.hgt` and see if it can fix it.

Comment: Same result as with `.DEM`

Comment: Strange... I can open it in QGIS2.18.13... just to check: where did you store header file (HDR)?

Comment: I had actually only downloaded the .DEM files, and so now I was able to open them with the .hdr files added!

Comment: AlexVestin or @Kazuhito please consider adding this comment as an answer so the question can be marked as answered instead of staying open.

Comment: Can I leave it to you, AlexVestin? Thanks @Kersten , I totally agree.

Comment: Yes sure, waited to see if you wanted to grab it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem (as @Kazuhito pointed out) that I didn't download the accompanying Header files (.hdr). With the header files in the same directory as the .DEM, they are able to be opened